# Primes that don't give a square when added any of the primes less than them

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, square-numbers

I am working on a maths project right now, and a really important part in that project is the primes that don't make a square when added to any primes below them. I have looked for these using code, and it seems that there are no primes satisfying this after 186481, up to 1000000(A million)(I have only checked until there because my PC is not so fast). Do they really end there? If yes, why a random number like 186481?

Comment: Well its worth pointing out that any sequence of the form "primes that X" if it does terminate at some prime will terminate at what probably seems like a weird number (if it isn't 2,3). Also there are A LOT of primes so its quite likely there might be a super massive number after 186481, why dont you list the sequence of all primes out on OEIS.org and see if it matches any known sequences

Comment: Well, it matches the sequence A305411 on the oeis, but there, there are only the first 46 terms

Comment: Yes, see [here](https://oeis.org/A305411). But there is a code for computing given. You could just compute more.

Comment: Yes I could compute more, but as I said my computer is not so fast, and I also asked it in case someone can show why there **doesn't** exist.

Comment: I looks like that there is no proof, and this is not unusual for problems of primes listed at OEIS. Why do you believe that there is an answer possible?

Comment: There are infinite many primes , nevertheless the desired property might hold only for a finite number of primes, the "weird" prime can well be the last one. I neither think that there is a satisfying explanation why this prime could be the last , nor do I have hope that we can prove or disprove that infinite many primes have the desired property.

Comment: Upto $10^8$ , there is no prime beyond the "magical" $186481$ with the desired property.

Comment: Still the case upto $10^9$

Comment: @Peter what code did you use? You got the results quite fast.

Comment: @Peter I would love it if you could send the code as well

Comment: Guessing you halved the search space by noting that only 3+1 mod 4 combinations could add to a square modulo 4 right. Or one prime be is 2

Answer (score 1):

Another way of stating the condition is that for all integers $x$ with $p \le x^2 < 2 p$, $x^2 - p$ is composite.

There are approximately $\sqrt{2p}-\sqrt{p}$ such $x$, and heuristically $x^2 - p$ has probability around $1/\log(p)$ of being prime, so the probability that none of them
are prime is about $(1 - 1/\log(p))^{\sqrt{2p}-\sqrt{p}} \approx \exp\left( - (\sqrt{2}-1)\sqrt{p}/\log(p)\right)$. This goes to $0$ faster than any power of $p$, and particular its sum converges, so we should expect only finitely many such $p$.
However, this is not a proof.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Should I credit you if I use it?

Comment: Sure, you can credit me.  But again I emphasize, this is not a proof that there are finitely many $p$, it just says it's plausible that there are finitely many.  BTW, I've checked that there are no more up to $5 \times 10^7$.

Comment: You might observe that the primes for which $p+2$ is a square are very sparse among these primes, and that for all other primes you have $x^2\equiv0\pmod{4}$. This means there are approximately half as many such candidates for $x$, and you end up with the square root of your probability estimate that none of them are prime, so you go to 0 a bit less quickly. The same conclusion holds nonetheless.

Comment: @RobertIsrael what code did you use? you got the result quite fast.

Comment: I've edited the OEIS page for sequence [A305411](https://oeis.org/A305411), and my Maple code will hopefully appear there soon, assuming the edits are approved.